# Как развернуть сайт в сети на node

Tags: node.js

Установил необходимые программы на сервер одного хостинга с ос ubuntu и перенес файлы проекта, установил nginx, node... локально все работает, но не понимаю как сделать чтобы можно было по ip и порту зайти на сайт с любого компьютера.

Сервер работает на порту 3000, данные по всем открытым портам:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

конфигурация nginx в директории nginx/example.com

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

когда запускаю команду на проверку ошибок nginx -t выводит:
nginx the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok

Comment: Нужен статический ip адрес, чтобы из сети к вашему проекту был доступ. Можно развернуться на каком нибудь хостинге например

Comment: я получил этот сервер от хостинга, пытался обращаться по ip c другого компьютера но не сработало

Comment: порты открыл? Что за хостинг?

Comment: хостинг regxa, сайт на порте 3000 крутится, я проверил, доменное имя не переносил, для начала думал что можно будет и через ip с портом открыть сайт

Comment: @sagfgggggggggggggggsfdhs тариф какой

Comment: @MoloF тариф EVA1

Comment: Для доспупа из внешней сети нужно настроить NAT на роутере + само приложение на ноде должен открыть чтение на порт от любого ip. проверить что там у нас по открытым портам для чтения можно посмотреть ```netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN``` возле порта который у вас открыт сайтом должно быть 0.0.0.0:3000 если там не 0.0.0.0 то смотрите код сайта. Так же надо проверить nginx и его конфигурационный файл.

Comment: а где listen 80?

Comment: изменил на твою кофигурацию , после ввел nginx -t, systemctl restart nginx, все правильно, но все равно сайт не работает глобально

Answer (score 0):

У Вас же есть nginx. Для минимального примера замените конфиг default на такой:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня уже был файл с кофигурацией я добавил в описание как устроено